# Fusion Tables - how to use no polygon colour for null-value cells?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Fusion Tables map visualisation.
Each country takes a polygon colour based on a cell numerical value. That's fine.
But cells with no value are coming back on the map with the colour designed for the maximum values.
That's wrong. They shouldn't have a colour at all.
How can I ensure this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a filter to select only rows where the cell value is not empty.

Comment: It would be nice to elaborate and add some code on how to do that.